# Limit of two logarithms subtraction

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I have the problem with calculating such limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\ln(n)}}{2^n}$$

After some transformations, I managed to get it to:

$$e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}((\ln n)^2 - n\ln(2))}$$

though I can't do anything more than that. I kind of know the result from the beginning, but I can't get past this moment. As there is a difference in the limit, I'm not sure how should I deal with it. I think I know that $n\ln(2)$ grows asymptotically faster, but it isn't enough proof to say the limit of that subtraction is $-\infty$, and, for the first limit: $e^{-\infty} = 0$.

Long story short: how should I solve this part? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}((\ln n)^2 - n\ln(2))$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use `\ln` to typeset $\ln$.

Comment: I've changed the parenthesis a little bit for $(\ln n)^2$ in order to be more clear.

Comment: You are almost done, the key observation now is that the $n$ term becomes infinitely larger than $(\ln n)^2$.

Comment: as an alternative we can also apply root or ratio test

Comment: Do you know the famous limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(\log n) ^a} {n^b} =0,a>0<b$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That was defined by one of the greatest professor I had the "Forgotten Limit"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

$$(\ln n)^2 - n\ln 2=(\ln n)^2\left(1-\frac{n\ln 2}{(\ln n)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Oh God, how did I not think of that? Going to check it out in a few minutes.

Comment: @Shuji Never mind! You are in time to fix ;)

Comment: FYI: managed to get it this way. I still can't believe I didn't think about it earlier. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Shuji I'm sure that the next time you will keep that in mind! And you have also received others great contributes and suggestions here from very skilled users. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 7):

For any $k$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(n)}n
&=\frac1n\int_1^n\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1n\int_1^k\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac1n\int_k^n\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\\[3pt]
&\le\frac{\log(k)}n+\frac1k\frac{n-k}n\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit of $(1)$, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}n\le\frac1k\tag2
$$
Since $(2)$ is true for any $k$, we must have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}n=0\tag3
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)^2}n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2\log\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\\
&=4\,\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\\[6pt]
&=4\cdot0^2\\[15pt]
&=0\tag4
\end{align}
$$

---

You can now use $(4)$ to evaluate
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(n)^2-n\log(2)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{\log(n)^2}n-\log(2)\right)\tag5
$$

Comment: Nice derivation! I generally use that $\frac{\log(n)^2}n\to 0$ from $\frac{\log(x)^2}x\to 0\quad x\to \infty$ by $x=e^y\to \infty$ and then $\frac{\log(x)^2}x=\frac{y^2}{e^y}$.

Comment: @gimusi: I figured there was a proof using the integral definition of log and so I tried this an liked how it worked. As shown, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}n=0$ is sufficient to show $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)^a}{n^b}=0$ for $a,b\gt0$

Comment: Yes it is really a nice derivation out of the standard ways I knew, really appreciated to see here! Thanks

Comment: @gimusi: another proof is  based on $\log x\leq x-1$. Just note that if $b>0$ then we choose $a$ with $0<a<b$ and then $a\log n=\log n^a<n^a$ so that $(\log n) /n^b<1/an^{b-a}\to 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Really nice and simple! Thanks a lot

Comment: I didn't know you can do it this way, too! Well, I'm completely no good when it comes to integrals. I will take my time to catch on it. Anyway, thanks for the help, I learned a lot through these answers and comments.